# SharePoint Sandbox Solution Failing based on Web Address used

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sandbox-solution

I have a SharePoint 2010 Sandbox Solution working perfectly on my dev machine if I view the page as: http://dev/page.aspx it works great.

However, if I view the page as http://dev.corp.company.com/page.aspx I get the following error:

```
Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: File Not Found.
```

Error throws even when viewing a blank web part with no code behind.

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]
```

is present.

Comment: How about catching the exception, logging and inspecting the problem? Then if you fail to figure out the problem post both the exception and your code.

Comment: I tried adding break points in the code, but the never fire. Are you suggesting looking at the log files, or is there an easier way? @OndrejTucny

Comment: Inspecting the log file in case you can't catch the exception in the IDE is an obvious step. Debugging ain't gonna be easy…

Comment: If you want to debug the sandbox code you need to attach the debugger to SPUCWorkerProcess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I need to configure alternate access mappings:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288609(office.12).aspx
>
> Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services
>   are accessing the site http://dev with the URL
>   http://dev.corp.company.com.  This may cause incorrect links to be
>   stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL
>   http://dev.corp.company.com as an AAM response URL.  For more
>   information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"
>
> ALSO:
>
> The Web application at http://skynet.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/ could
>   not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL
>   should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need
>   to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean
>   contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite_SubsetProxy.SPSite__Factory(String
>   requestUrl)